# Group BY combined with SUM() while returning first record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an inventory table where I want to `GROUP BY` different lots of the same mfgpn so I use a `SUM()` function on the quantity to combine like records. I want to try and pull the last MANUFACTURER on record for the group as it is probably the most current/accurate, but I seem to have trouble getting the MANUFACTURER field to GROUP all the common part numbers under the last MANUFACTURER so I still have a bunch of duplicate records in the results.

I currently have the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT SUM([QTY]) AS QTY
      ,[MFGPN]
    ,  (SELECT TOP 1 Manufacturer FROM [post].[dbo].[BF-prefix] B2 WHERE B2.MFGPN=MIN(B.mfgpn)) AS MANUFACTURER
  FROM [post].[dbo].[BF-prefix] B
  GROUP BY mfgpn, MANUFACTURER
  ORDER BY MFGPN ASC
```

I'm running on SQL Server 2008 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

You could use window functions to achieve what you need:

```
;WITH T AS
(   SELECT  MFGPN,
            Manufacturer,
            SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY MFGPN) AS Qty,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MFGPN ORDER BY Manufacturer) AS RowNumber
    FROM    [Post].[dbo].[BF-prefix]
)
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

I am just not sure how you are defining "last manufacturer" I assume you have a date field for this, so you'll probably need to change the order by clause in this line

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MFGPN ORDER BY Manufacturer) AS RowNumber
```